# Query to detect static locks and remove them dynamically

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

We are currently executing an overnight batch and due to some issues ( still under analysis) we are getting an error of table lock after the batch is completed. Right now we are manually removing the lock before batch everyday, is there a way that can be used to automate the search for table locks in DB and remove if any found ?

I am currently running these 2 lines of code :

`select distinct(table_name),owner,STATTYPE_LOCKED from dba_tab_statistics where owner = 'owner' and STATTYPE_LOCKED = 'ALL';`

`EXEC DBMS_STATS.unlock_table_stats('owner','table1');`

`EXEC DBMS_STATS.unlock_table_stats('owner','table2');`

Any help on this would be very much helpful!

TIA

Comment: What exactly is the table lock error you're getting?

Comment: Object statistics are getting locked on two of the tables.